# How should I solder one board to another?

Tags: soldering, prototyping

I have a small power regulator/charger and a IOIO-OTG that I'm trying to solder onto my protoboard. My current idea is to use male/male headers. Is there another way? What is the best practice when doing these things?

Comment: My two methods are stick the male headers through the holes and solder, or use sockets.

Comment: Prototyping is a "whatever is most practical and quick for you" proposition.  If you have male headers,  can make them fit quickly,  then do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect two boards together both physically and electrically, it is not good practice to try to do both at the same time. The problem is that eventually the electrical connections will fail under mechanical load - compared to just about any other metal, solder is soft and weak. There's an old saying: "What's the difference between military and hobbyist approach to solder? Answer: the military thinks solder has zero strength, while the hobbyist thinks it has infinite strength." In practice, neither is correct, but without knowing the details of the mechanical loads to be placed on your boards, and the reliability / operational lifetime you need, I recommend not soldering the boards together. Use Kamil's approach along with a mechanical connection.

Answer (score 1):

Just use headers like in Arduino. This is best practice.

[image]

Image source: [adafruit.com](http://www.adafruit.com/products/243)